# How is multiple selection working in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

The relevant snippet of HTML:

```
<span class="a">
<div class="fieldname">Question 1</div>
<input type="text" value="" name="q1" />
</span>
```

The relevant jQuery:

```
$.each($('.a'), function(){
$thisField = $('.fieldname', $(this));
});
```

What exactly is being set to `$thisField`? If my understanding of multiple selectors in jQuery is correct, it should be grabbing the outer `<span>` element AND the inner `<div>` element. But for some reason, if I use `$thisField.prepend("hi");` it ends up putting `hi` right before the text `Question 1`, but not before `<div>`. I thought multiple selectors would grab both elements, and that `prepend()` adds `hi` to the beginning of BOTH elements, not just the `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling convention you are using is not a "multiple-selector" it is in fact searching within the context (`$(this)`) for a selector  (`'.fieldname'`).  [See docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery).

You could do this to get the `<div>` and the `<span>`:

```
$(this).find('.fieldname').andSelf().prepend('hi');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.fieldname', $(this));` is equivalent to `$(this).find('.fieldname');`

don't get this confused with something like: `$('.class1, class2');`.

`$('.class1, class2');` has only one parameter inputted.

Comment: so there is a difference betwee $('.class1', '.class2'); and $('.class1', $(this)); and the only difference is that using $(this) as the second means it's shorthand for find() and not a multiple selector? that's the only distinguishing factor?

Answer (score 0):

"The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection" http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Since you're targeting all elements with class "fieldname" within an element that has "a" class the output is right.

Answer (score 0):

> But for some reason, if I use
>   `$thisField.prepend("hi");` it ends up
>   putting hi right before the text
>   `Question 1`, but not before `<div>`.

Did you try this?

```
$.each($('.a'), function(){
  $('hi').insertBefore($('.fieldname', $(this)));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with multiple selectors, cause what I see you're doing is just selecting the `<div class="fieldname">`. All [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) is doing is adding `hi` before the content of that `div`.

So here you're not selecting more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selectors work inside the selector **string**..

like this

```
$multiple= $('.fieldname, a'); 
// this will select all <a> elements and all elements with class 'fieldname'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('.a')
```

means "for each element that has class=a" (in this case, only your span), so if your div also had class=a then you would see the outcome you expected.